# Why is an Ajax script not defined in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, antiforgerytoken

I added tinymce rich text editor to my ASP.NET MVC on .NET 4.7.2 web app.

The problem is: I can't post rich text content because of ASP.NET antiforgery-block.

So I am trying to get the AF-token into the request header with AJAX and compare it with the one generated in back-end, but it's not working. The `AntiforgeryCookie` is generated, but the script is not executed. Jquery 3.7.0.js is included and rendered.
Firefox debug  console tells me: "$ is not defined".

Any ideas?

```
@model Blog.Data.Posts

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
    }
    else
    {
        Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    }
    string token = TokenHeaderValue();
}
<head>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea'
        });
    </script>
</head>

@using (Html.BeginForm(FormMethod.Post))
{
    //creates AF hidden field
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    //TODO:
    //put the value in the header!

    @functions
    {
        public string TokenHeaderValue()
        {
            string cookieToken, formToken;
            AntiForgery.GetTokens(null, out cookieToken, out formToken);

            return cookieToken + ":" + formToken;
        }
    }

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        ajax({
            url: "~/Posts/Create/",
            type: "post",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: {}, // JSON data goes here
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                'RequestVerificationToken': '@token'
            }
        });
    });
</script>


    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Beitrag erstellen</h4>
        <hr />
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <textarea name="Text"></textarea>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Text, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="UserId" value="@ViewBag.UserId" />

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "AdminMainMenu")
    }
    else
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", "Users")
    }
</div>

<!--Der Inhalt wird vom _Layout/_LayoutAdmin gerendert. -->
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)